# how to add pagination to search product page in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to add pagination to my searching product item view using my show controller

This is my controller

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $categories = Item::all();

        $products = Item::find($id)->products->paginate(3);

        return view('category.index', compact('categories', 'products'));
    }
```

This is my view

```
@extends('layout.front')


@section('page')

<div class="row" id="portfolio">


    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-top:20px;">

                <nav class="main-nav">
                    <ul class="main-nav-ul">
                        <li style="background-color: #343A40; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 600;" id="sidebar-header"><a>Product List</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/computer') }}" style="font-weight: 600;">Computer<span></span></a>
                            <ul>
                                @if(!empty($categories))
                                    @forelse($categories as $category)
                                        <li><a href="{{ route('category.show', $category->id)}}">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>

                                    @empty
                                        <li>No data found</li>
                                    @endforelse
                                @endif
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="font-weight: 600;">CCTV</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="font-weight: 600;">Gaming</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->

            <div class="col-lg-9">


                <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">


                    @if(!empty($products))
                        @foreach($products as $key=>$product)
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item" id="items">
                                <div class="card h-100">

                                    <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="/storage/{{ $product->image }}" alt="Product Image"></a>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">
                                            <a href="#">{{ $product->category_name }}<br />{{ $product->item_name}}</a>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p class="card-text" style="color: #A9A9A9;text-decoration: line-through;">LKR {{ $product->old_price}}</p>
                                        <h4 style="text-align: center; color: #fff;"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-dark btn-block">LKR {{ $product->new_price}}</a></h4>

                                        {{--@endforelse--}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif

                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-9 -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">{!! $products->links() !!}</div>

@endsection
```

i used laravel default pagination and customize my bootstrap pagination to laravel.

But in my show function in controller pagination not working. how to fix searching products pagination.

i used links method. but it's not working for this view.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">{!! $comproducts->links() !!}</div>
```

Comment: What does "`not working`" mean? Get any errors? Look at `storage/logs/laravel.log` for any errors that might show up.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using pagination anywhere in the code. Please check the documentation on how to add pagination. You need to use `paginate` function when making the db call, and then use paginator links.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination

Comment: i used this link to my view   <div class="col-lg-12">{!! $comproducts->links() !!}</div>

Comment: you keep changing the question. and yes, adding `->paginate()` is also required

Comment: i used this paginate() to my $product object and it shows me error

Comment: you need to paginate the database results, not the products fetched from those results. LIke- `Item::find($id)->paginate(3);`. Do checkout the documentation page I've mentioned int he answer.

Comment: i used this but in my links div $product says undefined

Comment: saw the error.. This will require debugging as the error is that your products variable isn't even there which is unrelated to any pagination error.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{$products->render()}}
```

put it below the end of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find pagination code here

Table:stocks PK:id,Varchar:name

StockController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as Controller;

class StockController extends Controller {

public function usaPage() {
    $stocks = DB::table('stocks')->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->paginate(50);

    return view('stock.usa', ['stocks' => $stocks]);
}
?>
```

usa.blade.php

```
   @section('content')
   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach ($stocks as $stock)
                    <tr><td> {{ $stock->name }}</a></td><td>  {{ $stock->id }}</td></tr>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
         @endsection
```